# How to get response from django rest api in jsend format?

Tags: python, json, django, jsend

I am a complete beginner in django and django rest framework. I want to get the response in the jsend format where success ,fail, error message and status code is displayed. Any video tutorial or blog tutorial will help a lot. The main problem is I couldn't find how to get back success ,fail, error message and status code.

Comment: you can refer official documentation of [django rest reamework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: which part? I tried reading the exceptions part but couldn't understand.